# How to use Firebase Auth with custom rest api?

Tags: firebase, rest, authentication, authorization

I'm currently thinking about using Firebase Auth system with my custom rest api service.
For example:

1. My custom api would authorise requests coming from angular app, but auth system begins in that
   Angular app, so there I would get authenticated.
2. Later on, I would pass a token received from firebase to communicate with my service.
3. That service would check if token is ok and then let me in to resources.

Is it possible to do ?

Comment: Sure, give it a try.